# button to dynamically duplicate dropdownlist populated in a div on php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

button to dynamically add more dropdownlist (populated by accessing MySQL database) in a div? sort of duplicating the initial one.

i've manage to duplicate a div which are only textboxes (so they are easier, no need to access database) with javascript. the javascript does the duplication.

below is the javascript

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 15;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Type: <input type='text' name='types[]'> <br> Desc: <input type='text' name='descs[]'> <p>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

the problem i'm facing is dropdownlist + populated through the database in the javascript. below is the drop down list that i wish to duplicate

```
        sqlconn();
        $sql="SELECT type FROM products";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<select type=\"type\">";      
        for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
            $products = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo "<option value='" . $products['type'] . "'>" . $products['type'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You cannot do it using JS since you need to access your DB - this should be done on the server-side. what you want to do is create a form which will submit to itself something like "&action=duplicate", this form should reside in a php file that will receive the POST/GET request, call the DB for a list of updated values and then create the new dropdown (make sure to pass the previous dropdown boxes as well in the HTTP request otherwise you'll loose them!)

Comment: where's the html of the drop down list??.. you are not able to populate the list with the cloned div??

Comment: i've edited my question showing the drop down list that i wish to duplicate. @alfasin i dun get what u mean sorry, if you could explain again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the following example and modify it.
Pay attention to the fact that I commented out the call to the DB and just printed a "fake" dropbox:

```
<?php
function getDropbox(){
    $res = "";
    /*sqlconn();
    $sql="SELECT type FROM products";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $res = "<select type=\"type\">";
    for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
        $products = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $res += "<option value='" . $products['type'] . "'>" . $products['type'] . "</option>";
    }
    $res += "</select>";
    mysql_close($con);*/
    $res = "<select type=\"type\"><option value='sas'>kiki</option>";
    return $res;
}

  echo "<html><body>    <table><form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><tr><td>";


  if(isset($_POST["check1"]) && $_POST["check1"] == "Yes"){
    $create = $_POST["check1"];
  }
  if(isset($_POST['num'])){
    $numOfDropboxes = $_POST["num"];
  }

  if ($numOfDropboxes == NULL){
          $numOfDropboxes=1;
  }
  if ($create != NULL){
      $numOfDropboxes++;
  }
  for($i=0; $i < $numOfDropboxes; $i++){
      $dropbox = getDropbox();
        echo "<tr><td>".$dropbox."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "create = $create [".$_POST['check1']."] and numOfDropboxes = $numOfDropboxes </br>";

  echo "</td> </tr><tr><td><input type=hidden id=\"num\" name=\"num\" value=\"$numOfDropboxes\" /><input type=checkbox id=\"check1\" name=\"check1\" value=\"Yes\" />Click here if you want to create a dropbox</td> </tr>";
  echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "</form></table></body></html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use AJAX then? 
Create dropdown element, send request to server for dropdown items, get'em and populate your list.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 15;


    function inAdd(divName){

         if (counter == limit)  {
              alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
         }
         else {
              var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
              newdiv.innerHTML = "Type: <input type='text' name='types[]'> <br> Desc: <input type='text' name='descs[]'> <p>";
              document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
              counter++;
         }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="foobar">
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="inAdd('foobar')" />
    </div>
    </html>
```

Try this,dynamically add's textbox's.. any content you want to add to them -- you need to get it from the server via ajax.. or from the `onclick` on the button.. hope this is issue what you were facing..

Comment: The problem is that this code does not get the information from the DB

Comment: @alfasin i was under the impression that populating the div is the issue.. if getting information from the db is the issue -- then,u need to make an ajax call -- get the info from the server , use that data to repopulate the list..

Comment: @alfasin is right. i'm trying to come up something with an AJAX now. not exactly good at it though.

Comment: @vinz http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml this should be a good place to start..

Comment: of course you can use ajax - but it's not a "must".
I'm working on a prototype - so you can take it and develop on top of it. I'll post it in a few minutes.

Comment: thanks all! 

i've manage to duplicate it once but i don't know how to do things like .appendChild(newdiv); 

but adding on in the div itself. and also getting the arrays in the later part.